# Crypting with a weak secret key using AES

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key, aes

I am using AES to encrypt some data, the problem is that I have to use a key that contains only 4 digits (like pin code), so anyone can loop 9999 times to find my key and decrypt my text. The data I am encrypting here is an SMS.

Is the any idea to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can add salts and iteration counts to a PBKDF all you want, but in the end the attacker only has 10K tries to go through, and that's peanuts.

The only sensible way to do this is to have a separate entity that performs the decryption. It can add secret entropy of its own to the key seed, and use a strong key. The entity would then place restrictions on the authentication with the PIN.

You might want to take a good look at your *system's security architecture* and see if you can change something to avoid this problem (access control, other login credentials etc. etc.).

Comment: I must encrypt and decrypt and the two extremities of communication (the mobile phone and the sms server), and I don't see how can I make restrictions since anyone who know the source code, can implement it somewhere and do the brute force, I think I should switch to the RSA.

Comment: thanks, but I am a beginner in cryptography, and I don't understand your suggestion about challenge response protocol, but for now I think RSA is more secure than AES in my case.

Comment: It certainly is for encrypting data to a server, but I've removed some comments as I am still figuring out the use case. Just distribute the public key in a secure key store (e.g. within your application) and encrypt using that. Only use RSA with PKCS v1.5 padding. If possible, you may authenticate your data with a key derived from the PIN. Beware of padding oracle and replay attacks. Sorry, no easy answer here.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but what i am planing to do is, to store the private key of the client and the public key of the server in the client side. In the server side, i will store his private key, and the public key of the client, so the two actors will encrypt and the decrypt, is this correct ? Another constraint, is that i am using SMS as communication channel, so the decrypted data must not have a huge length than the original data (160 chars only per SMS), and i think the padding add more data to the cipher text :(

Comment: Well, yes, at least you got the function of the asymmetric keys right. There is quite a lot more to it than that though.

Comment: @DahmadBoutfounast RSA with a private key derived from a 4-digit PIN will certainly not be more secure than AES with a secret key from such a PIN. There is simply not enough entropy, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Removed my comment about adding a salt, everyone who pointed this out was correct.  You could perhaps increase the time complexity of decryption, such that a brute-force attack would take a prohibitively long time.

Edit: read this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6719/how-would-you-store-a-4-digit-pin-code-securely-in-the-database

Comment: The link is great, but as the link suggests, just adding a salt won't help for a search space of just 10K entries, at least not for *storage*.

Comment: it deosn't help in my case, I send the crypted data not storing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the same aproach as ATM machines: after someone enters an incorrect PIN three times, that account is temprorarily invalid (you can also set a along time-out) and that user will have to undertake some kind of action (e.g. click a confirmation link in an e-mail) in order to reactive his/her account.

You'll also have to salt the PIN with an unique property of that user (preferably a string that was randomly generated when that user was registered). I also recommend adding an additional salt to all hashes that is either hard-coded or read from a config file (usefull in case your database is compromised but the rest isn't).

This approach still leaves you vulnerable to an attack where someone chooses a single PIN and brute-forces usernames. You can take some countermeasures to this by applying the same policy to IP-adresses, but that's still far from optimal.

EDIT: If your goal is to encrypt traffic rather than to hash PIN's, you should use HTTPS or another protocol based on public-key cryptography, that way you won't have to use your PIN for encrypting these SMS's.

Comment: I don't see how can I do this in my case !! I have a mobile application that sends encrypted SMS to a server, so a man-in-the-middle can intercept my message and do the brute force since he knows i am using AES and how i am using it.

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted to use that encryption for a different purpose. I've extended my answer.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend implementing any encryption algortithm yourself, since those might be vulnerable to side-channel attacks or could contain bugs that can be exploited. There are probably some very reliable and heavily tested implementations available for your platform, so use those.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you can only enter 4 digits, pad the keylength in the application with either phone number of sender or something like that?

Comment: a hacker will do the same, since he knows my phone number, no ?

Comment: could you explain why you are limited to 4 digit keys then?

Comment: it's a system specification, and i must could edit that code from the phone (Interactive Voice Response), so it must be numeric only.

Comment: then as steve said, add a salt that only you know to the code so that it's not a straight AES decrypt. out of interest, are you storing this data? or sending it?

Comment: no i send it, and the server must decrypt it, read it, and send me back a crypted answer, and i should decrypt it again to read it

Comment: so you're doing transport encryption as opposed to storage based encryption? you're using the wrong crypto for the job. [Transport Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

Comment: what do you mean ?? should I use asymmetric encryption ??